# How to achieve aggregations in spark structured streaming foreachBatch method?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a usecase that,

I need to read the records from the datasource and write it to multiple sinks including kafka, along with some aggregations.

Here is how my pseudo code looks like,

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.readStream()......

dataset.writeStream().foreachBatch(
// do some processing, including aggregations
// write it to multiple sinks
batch.write().format('kafka').save();
).start().awaitTermination();
```

when I tried some aggregation method inside the foreach, by default it is taking append mode and dropping the older aggregations. Hence output contains only the  result of current batch.

My requirement is, when ever a second batch of data arrives, it should get merged with the result of first batch.

Ex : For the query, `dataset.groupBy("id").count(value)`

**if first batch of input is:** {"id":1, "value":1}, {"id":1, "value":1}

**output:** {"id":1, "value": "2"}

**second batch input:**
{"id":1, "value":3}, {"id":1, "value":2}

**output :** {"id":1, "value":5}

**Expected output :** {"id":1, "value":7}

How to achieve this in spark?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Above example is a DStream example, not a structured streaming. You need to think Spark Structured Stream as loading data into an unbounded table.

Assuming the data source is kafka, here is a basic example of Structured Streaming. Please note that schema inference is not possible with ReadStream and WriteStream Api. Schema need to come from data source connector, in this case Kafka.

```
val df = sparkSession
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9031")
  .option("subscribe", "word-count")
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
  .load()

val query = df
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING) as key", "CAST(value AS STRING) as value")
  .as[(String, String)]
  .select(from_json($"value", schema = schema).as("data"))
  .writeStream
  .format("parquet")
  .option("path", "/parquet/word-count/")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/word-count-chkpnt")
  .trigger(ProcessingTime("10 second"))
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
  .start()
```

Use .trigger() function to create micro batches and outputMode to save the result for each micro batch. In this example, I am creating a micro batch every 10 seconds, `.trigger(ProcessingTime("10 second"))` and appending the each event in the stream as a row to the parquet file `.outputMode(OutputMode.Append())`

In your case, you need to use .trigger() with a micro batch interval of your choice and `.outputMode(outputMode.Update())` to insert new keys with a value or update the existing keys with incremented value.

The below part is where your aggregation logic will go. You can break down the aggregation logic into a separate data frame and write the data frame as a stream instead of chaining
for readability.

```
.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING) as key", "CAST(value AS STRING) as value")
  .as[(String, String)]
  .select(from_json($"value", schema = schema).as("data"))
```

[Another example](https://github.com/gargshiva/Spark-Structured-Streaming/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/learn/structured/stream/aggregation/StatefulWordCount.scala) of structured streaming.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and putting this up.

But my usecase is littlebit different, I need to write the processed data to multiple sinks in a efficient way, hence I'm goinf ahead with foreachbatch. I need to know how to achieve update mode on the microbatched datasets that are arriving inside foreach batch.

Comment: check [this](https://blog.knoldus.com/stateful-transformation-on-dstream-in-apache-spark-with-example-of-wordcount/)